# Libgdx: how does dispose() work?

Tags: libgdx, memory-efficiency

My game uses a lot of images, for the over-world, battle screens, chats, etc. I'm really meticulous when it comes to memory management, and I've noticed that even though I dispose every image when I load in a new one, the memory never goes down.

Isn't this what Dispose() should do or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: "I dispose every image when I load in a new one"  -- Possibly because you are loading a new image when you dispose, therefore, using memory up again making it look like it didn't dispose?

Comment: Also, depending on how you're profiling your memory usage, you could be looking at the wrong values or misinterpreting the data.

Comment: @Jon I mean it still increases, not stays the same. Also I use my Task Manager to check the memory usage.

Comment: Task Manager isn't really the best tool for this job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disposal patterns like LibGDX's in languages with GCs often have to do with releasing un-managed resources in addition to (or instead of) managed memory. This true with C#'s [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, and based on [the documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management) LibGDX's pattern serves a similar purpose.

This means that simply looking at private working-set CPU-side RAM use may not be an accurate way to tell if disposing of the resource is "working as intended" or not. For example, if a texture isn't caching its image data on the CPU (expecting it to be on the GPU), then disposing it will not impact CPU-side memory appreciably at all.

LibGDX's source code is on GitHub, so you can take a look at the specific implementations of the dispose method. For example, [texture's](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.java#L188) or [pixmap's](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.java#L314).